# What does key mean in indexedDB?

Tags: html, indexeddb, database, nosql

I'm learning how to use indexedDB right now.

There is one thing that's confusing me.

I've learned that object stores in indexedDB are like database tables in Relational Database.

But, I don't understand what keys do in indexedDB.

I've read many articles on indexedDB, but they don't explain much what keys are in indexedDB.

So, I'd like to make it clear to me!

Could anyone please tell me what keys are in indexedDB, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is what you might expect from a key-value store database. You can find about [IndexedDB key here](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-construct). Key refer to both primary key and secondary (index) key.